# Wordpress user follower to another user

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, user-profile

My client want functionality a user can follow to another user & display follower users post in login user profile.

I have also used user profile plugin but it's does not given me output that my client want.

I have also searched many plugins but i could not found anything related on it.

Does somebody know about it , please help me ?

Comment: can you clear the following process little bit more ? I think you need to use BuddyPress plugin

Comment: I want to put follow button on user profile page so whenever any user visit profile of user he can follow that user.